# Can Fock states be teleported using conventional boson-based platforms in continuous variables?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, quantum-teleportation

Is it possible to teleport Fock states using conventional bosons-based platforms in continuous variables? Usually with bosons-based platforms people perform two-mode squeezing, beam splitter, and EPR (Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen) measurements, but they primarily handle teleport vacuum states. Can this protocol be adapted for general Fock states (number states) with fidelity higher than the classical limit (F=0.5), or are modifications necessary? Any insights on this topic would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  You can of course teleport single photon (N=1) states.  Is there any specific approach you are thinking of?

Comment: My approach is based on the implementation of a teleportation protocol as shown in the Fig.2 of this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0604027.pdf. Could you provide details of how to teleport a single photon please?

Comment: Yes, that's a good paper. Fig. 2 (and Fig. 1 as well) show the basic mechanism. To be clear, what is being teleported is a state. And you still need the classical bits (results from Alice's apparatus) to complete the process. I would note that the Continuous Variable (CV) case is much more complicated (at least to me :). I almost exclusively reference the more common polarization setup (Fig. 1) which is also used for Entanglement Swapping.